# Expand product of sums to a minimum sum of products

Tags: algorithm, math, wolfram-mathematica, boolean-logic, algebra

I'm trying to write a [Petrick's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petrick%27s_method), which is a technique for [Quine–McCluskey algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm).

Assume I have a math equation, which consists of `+` and `*`. For example:

```
(K+L)(K+M)(L+N)(M+P)(N+Q)(P+Q)
```

How can I exand the equation to get all of the sum of products, like this?

```
K*K*L*M*N*P + K*K*L*M*N*Q + .... (63 terms)
```

(You can see the inferred result with [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand%20(K%2BL)(K%2BM)(L%2BN)(M%2BP)(N%2BQ)(P%2BQ)))

Comment: How are you storing the products?

Comment: I don't get the question. Are you looking for the Mathematica command? That would be simply `Expand[(K + L) (K + M) (L + N) (M + P) (N + Q) (P + Q)]`.

Comment: @Michael I meant how I could get the result similar to WolframAlpha.

Comment: @Charles I can use immutable array of char.

Comment: For some reason the result from WolframAlpha is not suitable for you -- perhaps because you're writing in some other programming language? But you need to say what you actually want for the question to be answerable.

Comment: there are no "immutable arrays" in mathematica.  also wolframalpha is not mathematica. You should remove the mathematica tag if the question is not about mathematica.  (there is a separate tag for wolframalpha)

Comment: @PaulHankin I want to write in a programming language, I created a new post for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42910887/boolean-algebraic-distributive-law-algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow doubt this is what you want, but to obtain the result as an array of characters...

```
w = Expand[(K + L) (K + M) (L + N) (M + P) (N + Q) (P + Q)];
x = ToString@InputForm[w];
z = StringReplace[x, y_ ~~ "^2" :> StringJoin[y, "*", y]]
```

> ```
> K*K*L*M*N*P + K*L*L*M*N*P + K*L*M*M*N*P + ... + L*M*N*P*Q*Q
> ```

```
DeleteCases[Characters@z, " "]
```

> ```
> {K,*,K,*,L,*,M,*,N,*,P,+, ... ,+,L,*,M,*,N,*,P,*,Q,*,Q}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I have got fewer terms than you expected - only five rather than 63:

[image]

As `Boolean` expressions:

```
(k+l) & (l+n) & (k+m) & (m+p) & (n+q) & (p+q)


knp + lmq + lmnp + klpq + kmnq
```

It might be interesting to look at tha `JavaScript` code behind [this site](http://www.mathematik.uni-marburg.de/~thormae/lectures/ti1/code/karnaughmap/). It is an implementation of *Petrick's* method in `JavaScript`.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your statement

"I'm trying to write a Petrick's method, which is a technique for Quine–McCluskey algorithm."

I will show you a

- ready to use implementation of Petrick's method and
- also a full fledged Quine & McCluskey Implementation and
- an explanation of the algorithm that I implemented

First of all, the complete solution can be found here:

[MCDC](https://github.com/Armin-Montigny/MCDC)

The source code is an elegant solution using set operations for an efficient implementation:

```
// Functor operator for applying Petricks methhod
ProductTermVector PetricksMethod::operator ()(const CNF& cnf)
{
    // We select an iterative approach. Start with the first Element of the CNF (which is a DNF)
    // And we store the result of each iterative operation again in this element
    DNF resultingDNF{ cnf[0] };
    // We will always start with the element 1 (not element 0) because in 0 is the initial value
    // or respectively the intermediate result
    for (CNF::size_type dnfInCnfIndex = 1; dnfInCnfIndex < cnf.size(); ++dnfInCnfIndex)
    {
        // Result of multipliying out the intermediate (initial) value with the current CNF Product term
        DNF intermediateCalculatedDNF;
        // Now go through all elements of the intermediate (initial) product term/DNF
        // For (1+2)(3+4)  this would be the (1+2) part
        for (const ProductTerm& productTermLeftSide : resultingDNF)
        {
            // Next we will iterate over all Minterms in the next DNF
            // For (1+2)(3+4)  this would be the (3+4) part
            for (const ProductTerm& productTermRightSide : cnf[dnfInCnfIndex])
            {
                ProductTerm productTerm{ productTermLeftSide }; // Resulting Product term is now 1
                // Add all elements from the right side
                productTerm.insert(productTermRightSide.begin(), productTermRightSide.end());   // Resulting Product term is now 1,2
                intermediateCalculatedDNF.insert(std::move(productTerm));  // Store this one
                // And continue to add more product terms. The stl::set will ensure the idempotence law and prevent memory waste
            }
        }
        // And now add all found terms to the result and continue with the next element of the right hand side
        // Please note: also here the set will prevent double terms
        resultingDNF = std::move(intermediateCalculatedDNF);
    }

    // Now we have the result (with 10 lines of code). The result contains all product terms in DNF
    // But for our prupose we are only interested in the minimum size terms
    // so, lets find the element with the minimu size (can be more than one)
    uint minLength{ narrow_cast<uint>(std::min_element(resultingDNF.begin(), resultingDNF.end(), [](const ProductTerm & left, const ProductTerm & right) noexcept {return left.size() < right.size(); })->size()) };
    // And from the big list of the DNF with all product terms, we copy all elements having the minimu size to the result. These are our best coverage sets
    ProductTermVector cheapestVector;
    // Copy result and return it to caller
    std::copy_if(resultingDNF.begin(), resultingDNF.end(), std::back_inserter(cheapestVector), [&minLength](const ProductTerm& pt) noexcept {return pt.size() == minLength; });
    return cheapestVector;
}
```

The number of net lines of code is 14. There are some additional definitions used, to make understanding and usage of types easier:

```
using BooleanVariable = uint_fast8_t;
using ProductTerm = std::set<BooleanVariable>;
using ProductTermVector = std::vector<ProductTerm>;
// Disjunctive Normal Form
using DNF = std::set<ProductTerm>;
// Conjunctive Normal Form
using CNF = std::vector<DNF>;

class PetricksMethod    // Functor
{
public:
    ProductTermVector operator()(const CNF& cnf); // Functor operator
};
```

Please note. The type "BooleanVariable" can also be a char, a string or whatever you like. That doesn't matter for the implementation, but will have an impact on the consumed memory.

The idea behind this algorithm is to use the "STL set" and to employ properties of set operations. If you look for example at the term (a+b)(c+d): If you want to multiply this out, then the result will be: ac+ad+bc+bd. If you treat a boolean variable as a special product term with just one member and implement this product term as a set, then the operation is to just add variables to existing sets. So, if you have a set containing "a" and if you want to multiply this with the set containing "b", then you can just add "b" to "a". The set will then contain "ab".

So, we will insert the set containing "b" to the set containing "a" and so on and so on. This we will do in a loop and will get 4 sets (product terms). These 4 sets make up a resulting DNF. The just calculated DNF can be combined further with additional terms of a CNF.

If we would have "(a+b)(c+d)(e+f)", we would treat it as "((a+b)(c+d)) (e+f)". We would first multiply out the first 2 MaxTerms, get (ac+ad+bc+bd) and apply the same algorithm on (e+f). We will always add new variables to existing sets. And this we will do iteratively, until the complete expression is evaluated.

The problem is the many many resulting subterms. But luckily, here the properties of the set, with unique sorted elements will help. For (a+b)(b+a) we would get ab+aa+bb+ba. The stl set will provide the idempotence law for us. Meaning "a" AND "a" is "a",   "b" or "b" is "b". So trying to add "a" to a set containing an "a" already, will not work. The result is still an "a". Same with complete product terms like 2 times "ab". They will not be added to a DNF double. So, the result of above operation is:

ab+aa+bb+ba --> ab+ab+aa+bb --> ab+aa+bb --> a+b+ab

With that approach, there will be no double terms and in general shorter terms.

But please be aware. The calculation time and the memory consumption will grow geometrically with the number of terms. So the function can only be applied with a limited number of variables / terms.

I hope I could give an understandable explanation. If you need more info, please ask.